# Search items that belong to list when list belongs to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search, serialization

I built a todo list API project and I need to add the option to search both items and lists. So far I am able to search lists only. The data is also serialized (AMS).

I have the query for lists happening in the controller as opposed to the model. I did this so that I could get the current_user 's list.

This is what I have:

*Models*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :items, through: :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy 
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

*Controllers*

```
class Api::ListsController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticated?

  def index
    if params[:name].present?
      lists = current_user.lists.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%")
    else
      lists = current_user.lists
    end
      render json: lists
  end
end
```

*Serializers*

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :username

  has_many :lists
end

class ListSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :permissions, :user_id

  has_many :items 
end

class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :list_id, :id, :name, :complete 
end
```

Since I had already built a front-end, the list and items are displayed in welcome#index. On that same page, I added a simple form to perform the search like so:

```
  <%= form_tag api_lists_path, :method => 'get', :id => "api_lists_search" do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

Currently, performing the search executes the correct request, and takes me to GET /api/lists?name=shopping which is then displayed in json. How could I pull the lists's items as well in the search? Having two search boxes seems clunky and even then, I'm not sure what the request path should look like.

Comment: Do you want that page to show items with that given name, or do you want to show the lists with the given name and the items those lists have?

Comment: The items with that given name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to search through my items (as well as my lists) by changing my index action to:

```
class Api::ListsController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticated?

  def index
    if params[:name].present?
      lists = current_user.lists.joins(:items).where(
        'lower(lists.name) LIKE ? or lower(items.name) LIKE ?', 
        "%#{params[:name].downcase}%",
        "%#{params[:name].downcase}%"
        )
    else
      lists = current_user.lists
    end
      render json: lists
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class Api::ListsController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticated?

  def index
    if params[:name].present?
      lists = current_user.lists.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%")
      items = current_user.items.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%")
    else
      lists = current_user.lists
    end

      results = items.any? ? lists + items : lists  

      render json: results
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to move the query for lists for users to the model, you can create a class method in the user model like;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :items, through: :lists

  def self.find_list(name)
    self.lists.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%")
  end
end
```

and call this from the controller with;

```
class Api::ListsController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticated?

  def index
    lists = current_user.lists
    lists = current_user.find_list(params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
    render json: lists
  end
end
```

You can then add a drop-down in the view to select whether to search for lists or items, create a method in user model for items and check in the controller for the value of the drop-down and call the respective method